Exhaust Fan on 20 amp breaker using 15 amp Switch
I'm adding an exhaust fan to my bathroom, as it's an old 1880s home that never had one. At first there was a 15 amp breaker using 14/2 cable feeding the lights and the outlets in the bathroom. I decided that with adding the exhaust fan though only being a few amp draw, it would be best to upgrade to 20 amp breaker and 12/2 wiring.
The outlets are 20 amp outlets. However, the 3 switches are all 15 amp. Is that ok? Two switches are toggle switches that work two different lights, and the 3rd switch is a timer switch that will run only the exhaust fan with light. So obviously none of the lights will pull more than 15 amps, but should I be concerned about the exhaust fan motor malfunctioning and drawing more amps than usual?

if the fan draws more than 15A and less 20A it's going to start a fire as many times with a 15A switch as it would with a 20A switch,  but I'm not code lawyer enough to bless this.
